# sorting list in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sorting, meteor

I try to sort my list but it works not the way i want it to.

```
Template.nummern.helpers({
    nummer: function(){
        var id= Session.get('StraßenId');
        return Nummern.find({'StraßenId': id },{sort: {Hausnummer: -1}});
    }
});
```

My goal is that the sort depends on the value of `"Hausnummer"` in this variables only numbers getting inserted and when i first insert "5" and then "2" the "5" is on top followed by the "2" but i want it the other way --> 12356869... and not sorted like the creation

I hope you can help me thank you ;)

Comment: So you want numbers in ascending order? Have you tried `{sort: Hausnummer: 1}}`?

Comment: syntax error ;(

Comment: What led you to a syntax error? Changing -1 to 1?

Comment: In your example you changed some brackets that got me the error and when i change -1 to 1 i get the same sorting only in the other direction.     I insert 4961 i get --> 1694

Comment: Ahh, I did have a missing `{`. Sorry! Could you provide an example snippet of your current output, and what you expect?

Comment: when i insert 13,5,8,1,4,7, i get  13,5,8,1,4,7 or 7,4,1,8,5,13 but i want to have it like this : 1,4,5,7,8,13

Comment: Is `Hausnummer` a *string* or a *number*?

Comment: Its a string ;)